# Contact Form Turkish Character

Tags: php, html, special-characters, contact-form

I freeze all the fields on the form and then issue the mail when I press the submit button. There is a Turkish character problem at the output of mail.

contact.html

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="well">
    <h3>İletişim Formu</h3>
    <form role="form" id="contactForm" data-toggle="validator" class="shake">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                <label for="name">Ad Soyad</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="" required data-error="Lütfen bu alanı doldurun.">
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="" required data-error="Lütfen bu alanı doldurun.">
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                <label for="telefon">Telefon</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telefon" placeholder="" required data-error="Lütfen bu alanı doldurun.">
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                <label for="konu">Konu</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="konu" placeholder="" required data-error="Lütfen bu alanı doldurun.">
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="sektor">Sektör</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="sektor" placeholder="" required data-error="Lütfen bu alanı doldurun.">
                <option value="Özel" selected="selected">Özel</option>
                <option value="Projeci">Projeci</option>
                <option value="Satıcı">Satıcı</option>
                <option value="Uygulayıcı">Uygulayıcı</option>
                <option value="Diğer">Diğer</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message">Mesajınız</label>
            <textarea id="message" class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="" required data-error="Lütfen bu alanı doldurun."></textarea>
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" id="form-submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg pull-right ">Gönder</button>
        <div id="msgSubmit" class="text-center hidden"></div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

form-script.js

```
$("#contactForm").validator().on("submit", function (event) {
    if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        // handle the invalid form...
        formError();
        submitMSG(false, "Tüm alanları doldurdunuz mu?");
    } else {
        // everything looks good!
        event.preventDefault();
        submitForm();
    }
});


function submitForm(){
    // Initiate Variables With Form Content
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var message = $("#message").val();
    var telefon = $("#telefon").val();
    var konu = $("#konu").val();
    var sektor = $("#sektor").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/form-process.php",
        data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&telefon=" + telefon + "&konu=" + konu + "&sektor=" + sektor + "&message=" + message,
        success : function(text){
            if (text == "success"){
                formSuccess();
            } else {
                formError();
                submitMSG(false,text);
            }
        }
    });
}

function formSuccess(){
    $("#contactForm")[0].reset();
    submitMSG(true, "Message Submitted!")
}

function formError(){
    $("#contactForm").removeClass().addClass('shake animated').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
        $(this).removeClass();
    });
}

function submitMSG(valid, msg){
    if(valid){
        var msgClasses = "text-center tada animated text-success";
    } else {
        var msgClasses = "text-center text-danger";
    }
    $("#msgSubmit").removeClass().addClass(msgClasses).text(msg);
}
```

form-process.php

```
<?php

$errorMSG = "";

// NAME
if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $errorMSG = "Name is required ";
} else {
    $name = $_POST["name"];
}

// EMAIL
if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Email is required ";
} else {
    $email = $_POST["email"];
}

// TELEFON
if (empty($_POST["telefon"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Telefon is required ";
} else {
    $telefon = $_POST["telefon"];
}

// KONU
if (empty($_POST["konu"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Konu is required ";
} else {
    $konu = $_POST["konu"];
}

// SEKTOR
if (empty($_POST["sektor"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Sektor is required ";
} else {
    $sektor = $_POST["sektor"];
}

// MESSAGE
if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Message is required ";
} else {
    $message = $_POST["message"];
}


$EmailTo = "simple@mail.com";
$Subject = "New Message Received";

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Telefon: ";
$Body .= $telefon;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Konu: ";
$Body .= $konu;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Sektör: ";
$Body .= $sektor;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $message;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From:".$email);

// redirect to success page
if ($success && $errorMSG == ""){
   echo "success";
}else{
    if($errorMSG == ""){
        echo "Something went wrong :(";
    } else {
        echo $errorMSG;
    }
}

?>
```

Mail Output

```
Name: Ahmet
Email: ahmetcadi@gmail.com
Telefon: 05636588110
Konu: Ã¼ÄŸ
SektÃ¶r: Ã–zel
Message: Ã¼ÄŸiÄŸ
```

Comment: You've not set the relevant `Content-Type` header for the email itself, only the `From` header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution of the problem. Erol Keskin Thank you.

```
$success = mail($EmailTo, '=?utf-8?B?'.base64_encode($Subject).'?=', $Body, 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "<br>".'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "<br>".'From: '.$email . "\r\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding charset parameter to your AJAX request, like so:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/form-process.php",
    data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&telefon=" + telefon + "&konu=" + konu + "&sektor=" + sektor + "&message=" + message,
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
    success : function(text){
        if (text == "success"){
            formSuccess();
        } else {
            formError();
            submitMSG(false,text);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert

```
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
```

at the top of your Head section. Example usage :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8"/>
     ...etc
</head>
...
```

Comment: I added all of them. But the problem continues.

Comment: kardeşim ekledim ama sorun devam ediyor.

Comment: $success = mail($EmailTo, '=?utf-8?B?'.base64_encode($Subject).'?=', $Body, 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n".'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n".'From: '.$email . "\r\n");

bunu bir denermisin dostum

Comment: sağol oldu fakat hepsini yan yana yazdı.

Comment: çok sağol erol kardeşim.

Comment: Sende sağol kardeşim.

Answer (score -1):

This is output in the email so you need to set the relevant header there as well; currently you're only setting the `From` header.

```
// send email
$success = mail(
    $EmailTo, 
    $Subject, 
    $Body, 
    "From: {$email}\r\nContent-Type: text/plain;charset=utf8"
    );
```

See the section on **Additional Headers** : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

As an aside, depending on the mailserver you may need to tweak your line terminators in the header string - Postfix expects them to be in the format relevant to the OS, so `\n` on *nix systems. It's *unlikely* to break anything but...

Comment: I have added the code you sent. But the problem continues.